# How can i know which object is preventing me from saving?

Tags: microstrategy

I'm working on a Microstrategy 8.1.525.151 Client with a Microstrategy Server 8.1. While creating a report i deleted some objects and after that, each time i try create or change any object (report, filter, attribute) i get the same error when i try to Save

The error is

'Cannot save, move or copy this  object because it has been changed in the Metadata'

I've tried refreshing the schema both in the client and server, deleted and recreated the objects (it only works on the server but doesn't refresh on the client) and also the menu Administration/Server/Purge Cache Objects

With the exception of the Microstrategy knowledge base (which i cannot access) all i have found is mentions of changing multiple objects, however i don't know which objects may be causing this error if any

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i used to solve it was to delete all attributes and reports  i created since i started having such a problem, (it was easier because it was all in a single folder for attributes and a single folder for reports and i suspect in certain cases also other objects would need deletion) also restarted the intelligence server

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot create/save any other object I'm afraid that your metadata are corrupted.

There are some utility provided by MicroStrategy to fix them, but I don't think they still support version 8.1. Your best shot is to try with MicroStrategy tech support.

You are the only one with this problem? other users can modify objects?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know i was the only one with the problem; i added the way i used to solve it. (had forgotten to publish the answer)